# Traffic lifghts to show level of data entry excel

Tags: excel

If this has already been answered elsewhere i apologise but i couldnt find what i was looking for.

I have a large database and need a quicker method to show me which rows are complete, partially complete or incomplete. I want the range to go by individual row. So if the row is completely empty it will show a red indicator, if its partially completed it will show amber, and if fully completed it will show green.

A traffic light style indicator would be ideal in this situation.

Can you help?

Comment: This would be easy to handle using SQL, assuming missing values were indicated by `NULL`.  Why did you tag a database question with Excel?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would assume the OP is using Excel as his DB, which is not ideal, but can be done

Comment: I am using excel for my DB as Access is reserved for certain users within the company. So i have to make do with good old excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP - I would suggest that you use conditional formatting, combined with a countif function at the end of the line. The countif would count the entries in the line. There would be two end points, namely 0 and X, which is when everything is completed.

Using the conditional format would entail setting the conditional to format the cells red if the countif = 0, and green if countif = X. Everything else would be amber.

Comment: Sorry, i may have caused confusion,

I have a cell range of J6, K6 & L6. If all of these cells are empty my signal column returns red, if one or two are complete, it returns amber, and if they are all complete it returns green. 

Hope that helps,